# How to evaluate the sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}$ when $n$ grows?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I need help with the following limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}}$$

Thanks.

Comment: See also: [How to find a limit of this sequence: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2986785),
[What is the value of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{i \cdot n}} } \right)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2440224)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice for large $n$, we expect $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}
\text{ behave like }\int_1^n \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} \sim 2\sqrt{n}$. This suggests
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \sim \int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} \sim 2\left( \sqrt{k+\frac12} - \sqrt{k-\frac12}\right)$$ and the terms $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}}$ 
in the summands is close to something "telescopable". To make this idea concrete, we observe:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}} \ge &
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k})} 
= \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})
= 2 \Big(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Big)\\
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}} \le &
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1})} 
= \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}) = 2
\end{align}$$

As a result,
$$\left|\;\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}} - 2\;\right| \le 2 \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} -\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right) < \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}
\quad\implies\quad \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}} = 2.$$

Comment: +1 Nice. An informal motivation would be to note that (for large $k$, using first order Taylor expansion) $\sqrt{k+1} \approx \sqrt{k} + 1/(2\sqrt{k})$, or $1/\sqrt{k} \approx 2(\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k})$ which can be regarded as a discrete analogous to the derivative $(2\sqrt{x})' = 1/\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 15):

Your sum can be interpreted as a Riemann sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}} = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{n}{k}}.
$$

Let $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$ and let $x_k = k/n$. Then 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}} = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{n}{k}} = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) \to \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

(Since the integral is improper, a little care is needed to justify the last step.)

Comment: How we can justify the last step?

Comment: So we need to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1-\varepsilon)}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)\right)$$ Right?

Comment: A good idea.  The caution at the end is a good one ... Riemann sums for a convergent improper integral may or may not go to the value of the integral.

Comment: @GEdgar At first, we don't konw if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)$$ converges (thus limit properties are not valid). So, how we can to prove the equality above?

Comment: This method is well known on physics community. It goes like this: $\xi \equiv k/n$. $\Delta\xi = 1/n \Longrightarrow n\Delta\xi = 1$. Then, $\displaystyle{\sum_{1}^{n}\left(kn\right)^{-1/2}
 =
 \sum_{1}^{n}\left(n\xi n\right)^{-1/2}n\,\Delta\xi
\to \int_{1}^{\infty}\xi^{-1/2}\,{\rm d}\xi}$ ( when $n \to \infty$ ) which is the quite fine @mrf answer.

Comment: Actually, the sum you give in your answer, if converted to integrals of step functions, converges to $f$ by [Monotone Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem).

Comment: This is a correction to my comment (above):
$\displaystyle{\sum_{1}^{n}\left(kn\right)^{-1/2}
 =
 \sum_{1}^{n}\left(n\xi n\right)^{-1/2}n\,\Delta\xi
\to \int_{1/n}^{1}\xi^{-1/2}\,{\rm d}\xi = 2 - 1/n}$

Answer (score 7):

mrf has the main idea.  But since the integral is improper (as mrf notes) some care is required.  Here is one way, using the Lebesgue theory...

Let $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$.  For fixed $n$, let $g_n$ be defined by $g_n(x) = \sqrt{n/k}$ for $(k-1)/n < x \le k/n$.  Then $0 < g_n(x) \le f(x)$ and $g_n(x) \to f(x)$ on $(0,1]$.  Since $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $(0,1]$, we have by the dominated convergence theorem $\int_0^1 g_n \to \int_0^1 f$.  That is:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{n}{k}} \to \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}
$$

**ASIDE**

Monthly problem 11376 has an example of how blindly saying "Riemann sum" can lead one astray.  The solution is on p. 283 of the March, 2010 issue.  The problem defines
$$
S_n(a) = \sum_{an \lt k \le (a+1)n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{kn-an^2}\;}
$$
for real $a$ and positive integer $n$, and asks for which $a$ does $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(a)$ exist.  **Many** solvers noted that $S_n(a)$ is a Riemann sum for
$$
\int_a^{a+1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-a}\;} = 2
$$
and then carelessly concluded that $S_n(a) \to 2$ for all $a$.  But, in fact, as the published solution shows, $S_n(a)$ converges if and only if $a$ is rational.

The problem here is the case $a=0$, and fortunately $0$ is rational.

Comment: Ha ha! I am one of those who falsely "proved" convergence.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to mrf's answer, I believe that Monotone Convergence also applies since this sequence of functions is pointwise monotone.

Comment: @robjohn: It is not monotone along $n$, but yes it is monotone along $2^n$, say.

Comment: @GEdgar I would like know how to prove that $S_n(a)$ converges if and only if $a$ is rational. Is it possible you post the solution of this problem?

Comment: Monthly problem 11376 of what journal?

Comment: "Monthly" means "American Mathematical Monthly" ... Solution by Vitali Stakhovsky is in the March 2010 issue, vol 11, no 3, p. 282.  If your library subscribes to the *Monthly*, see it there.  You may try https://www.scribd.com/document/354083365/AMM-2010-N3 and scroll down to p 94 of 101 ... but since that page is presumably illegal, it may not be around for long.

Answer (score 5):

Think about $$\int_0^1 f(x)dx,~~~f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$

Indeed: $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i\right)\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$

Comment: I think your solution is valid if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\frac{b}{n}=\lim_{a\to 0^+}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i\right)\frac{(b-a)}{n}\right)$$ So, how to prove it?

Comment: Nice work, Babak! +1