# What is the value of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{i \cdot n}} } \right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, riemann-sum

> How can I calculate this limit: 
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \vphantom{1}i \cdot n}} } \Bigg)$$

Note: I think it has something to do with some Riemann sum, but I can't get anywhere, I tried to set $n$ as the number summands and $\frac1n$ as the width of each part. But that doesn't help; it gives: $\frac1n\sum\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{i}}$

Comment: @VerkhotsevaKatya Thanks for your efforts to improve formatting of the questions. However, please avoid using `\displaystyle`, `\dfrac` and similar commands in the titles. For more details see here: [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9687)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, o.k. Thank for advising.

Comment: See also: [How to find a limit of this sequence: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2986785), [How to evaluate the sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}$ when $n$ grows?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482003)

Answer (score 4):

Although the sum at hand can be rewritten as a lower Riemann sum
for an integral $\displaystyle\;\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}} = \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{n}{k}}$$
It doesn't mean we can directly claim the limit of the sum equal to the integral. This is because the intergrand $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ diverges at $x = 0$ and the upper Riemann sum of the integral doesn't exist. 
To proceed along this route, more justification is needed.

If you really want to go along this route, look at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1745876/59379) for a related question.
It shows that when your intergrand is non-negative, decreasing and the improper
Riemann integral exists, the limit of the sum still equal to the improper Riemann integral.

In this answer, we use a different approach, we will bound the sum directly.

For $k \ge 1$, we have
$\displaystyle\;\frac{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}}{2} \le \sqrt{k} \le \frac{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}{2}$, this leads to
$$2(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \ge \frac{2}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}} = 2(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})
$$
Summing $k$ from $1$ to $n$ and take advantage of the fact that the terms on LHS and RHS are telescoping, we obtain

$$
2\sqrt{n} \ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = 2(\sqrt{n+1} - 1) \ge 2\sqrt{n} - 2
\quad\implies\quad
2 \ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{nk}} \ge 2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
Sim $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} = 2$, by squeezing, we can conclude
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}} = 2$$

Comment: +1 for the remark about Riemann integral approach which leads to an improper integral. The use of squeeze seems appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  Just think of ${1\over n}\sum{\sqrt n\over\sqrt i}$ as ${1\over n}\sum f(i/n)$ with $f(x)={1\over\sqrt x}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: that figures it, then the expression would be the Riemann sum of $\int_0^1(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})dx$, which is 2. Should I mark the problem as solved?