# How to find a limit of this sequence: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, radicals

How to fing a limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}}?$$
I had only two minds about this. First of them was that it looks like $\frac{1^k
+…+n^k}{n^{k+1}}$ which limit is $\frac{1}{k+1}$. The second is to look at square of $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + .. + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, but it is a kind of a monster. I think, I need a formula for $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + .. + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, but I don’t know it.

Comment: You know that you can take the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ in front of the sum, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. But I don’t know what to do after that.

Comment: @Vremennik You should show your work and effort on it. Do not ask questions without context to avoid downvoting and closure.

Comment: @Vremennik You need to add that effort and try directly in the question not in comments.

Comment: @gimusi I added it in the question.

Comment: @Vremennik Well done, what about the given hint?

Comment: See also: [What is the value of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{i \cdot n}} } \right)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2440224), [How to evaluate the sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}$ when $n$ grows?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482003).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}$ when $n$ grows?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482003/how-to-evaluate-the-sum-frac1-sqrtn-frac1-sqrt2n-cdots-frac1)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{kn}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac k n}}$$

then refer to

- [Perfect understanding of Riemann Sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972643/505767)

Comment: Here the function $f(x) =1/\sqrt{x}$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ as it is unbounded. But the integral on $[0,1]$ exists as an improper Riemann integral and due to monotone nature of function the Riemann sum approach can be used here. See this answer for link between Riemann sum and improper Riemann integral: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1745876/72031

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to prove that
$$ H_n^{(1/2)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = 2\sqrt{n}(1+o(1)) \tag{1}$$
you are done, the limit is $2$. On the other hand

$$ \frac{H_{n+1}^{(1/2)}-H_n^{(1/2)}}{2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n}}=\frac{2\sqrt{n+1}+2\sqrt{n}}{4\sqrt{n+1}}\to 1\tag{2}$$
hence $(1)$ is a straightforward consequence of Cesàro-Stolz.
Through creative telescoping or just induction you may actually prove the stronger bound
$$2\sqrt{n}-\tfrac{3}{2}\leq H_n^{(1/2)}\leq 2\sqrt{n}-1.\tag{3}$$