# How to prove the series ${S_n}$ converges where $S_n$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k\cdot n}}$ and what is the limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove the series ${S_n}$ converges where $S_n$ is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k\cdot n}}$$

and what the limit is?

I thought it was $p$-series where $p=1/2<1$ so it must diverge but according to the question, it must converge, I'm not sure about which convergence test I can use.

Any tip is much appreciated

Comment: Riemann sum. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: $S_n$ is a sequence, not a series. The limit is $2$.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2986785/505767

Answer (score 4):

By [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) ($*/\infty$ case):
\begin{align}
& \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}{\sqrt{n}} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1}}}{\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n}}
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1}}(\sqrt{n + 1} + \sqrt{n}) \\
=& 1 + \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n + 1}} = 2. 
\end{align}